# I can't create this PostgreSQL Query: Grouping by a different condition to the "order by" condition

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count, sql-order-by

I need to order my query in a different way i need to group my tables. I need to count how many men are in every department, but organize the query by quantity of people (Not only men, but also women) in every department, in descending way.

This is the diagram and the code of the tables:

[Relational model of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEj2.png)

```
 CREATE SCHEMA Academico;

CREATE TABLE Academico.PAIS(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION varchar(120) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PAIS PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Academico.DEPARTAMENTO(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
CODIGO int NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION varchar(120) NULL,
IDPAIS int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTAMENTO PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Academico.CIUDAD(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CODIGO int NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION varchar(120) NULL,
IDDEPARTAMENTO int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CIUDAD PRIMARY KEY (ID));


ALTER TABLE Academico.DEPARTAMENTO
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DEPARTAMENTO_PAIS FOREIGN KEY(IDPAIS)
REFERENCES Academico.PAIS (ID)
on delete restrict on update restrict;

ALTER TABLE Academico.CIUDAD
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CIUDAD_DEPARTAMENTO FOREIGN KEY(IDDEPARTAMENTO)
REFERENCES Academico.DEPARTAMENTO (ID)
on delete restrict on update restrict;


CREATE TABLE Academico.SEXO(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION varchar(120) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_SEXO PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE Academico.TIPODOCUMENTO(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(30) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPCION varchar(120) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TIPODOCUMENTO PRIMARY KEY (ID));


CREATE TABLE Academico.PERSONA(
ID int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(10) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO varchar(30) NOT NULL,
IDSEXO  int NOT NULL REFERENCES Academico.SEXO(id),
IDCIUDAD int NOT NULL REFERENCES Academico.CIUDAD(id),
DOCUMENTO varchar(50) NOT NULL,
IDTIPODOCUMENTO  int NOT NULL REFERENCES Academico.TIPODOCUMENTO(id),
FECHANACIMIENTO date NULL CHECK (FECHANACIMIENTO > '1900-01-01'),
FEvarcharEGISTRO date NOT NULL DEFAULT  Now() ,
email varchar (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PROFESION varchar(12) NULL,
PERFIL varchar(120) NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_PERSONA PRIMARY KEY
(ID) );
```

I tried this two querys that give me the expected results but in a separated way:

```
select 
    d.nombre as _departamento, s.nombre as sex, count(1) as total_sexo
from 
    academico.persona p, academico.sexo s,
    academico.ciudad c, academico.departamento d 
where 
    p.idsexo = s.id 
    and p.idciudad = c.id 
    and c.iddepartamento = d.id
    and upper( s.nombre ) = 'MASCULINO'
group by 
    d.id,
    s.id 
order by 
    d.nombre
    
-- =======================================================
-- I don't know how to "merge" these two into one query 
-- =======================================================  

select 
    d.nombre as _departamento,  count(1) as total_gente
from 
    academico.persona p, academico.ciudad c,
    academico.departamento d, academico.sexo s 
where 
    p.idciudad = c.id 
    and c.iddepartamento = d.id
    and p.idsexo = s.id 
group by 
    d.id
order by 
    total_gente desc
         
;
```

I need to get those results with only one query

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired/expected results of that data. Make sure you have data that each query would independently select and a couple neither would select. Use text - **no images**. Even better create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use for the `FILTER (WHERE...)` construct.

```
...
count(1) as total_gente, 
count(1) filter (where upper( s.nombre ) = 'MASCULINO') as total_masculino
...
```

And then take the `upper( s.nombre ) = 'MASCULINO'` out of the main where clause.